# How to adjust session duration of Google Analytics real time

Tags: firebase, google-analytics, firebase-analytics

I saw a post that suggested it was possible to adjust the session duration tracked by Google Analytics Realtime (for Firebase) from the default duration of 30 minutes in a settings dialog in the "admin settings", but I can't find the admin settings on the firebase console.

Where can I find it?

Answer (score 0):

You could adjust it on the Google Analytics Console. You'll find the Admin page on the lower left panel.

[image]

Here's the full step to change the default timeout of 30 minutes for web sessions:

- In the left navigation, click **Admin**.
- In the Property column, click **Data Streams**.
- Click **Web** and then click a web data stream.
- In the web stream details, click **Configure tag settings** (at the bottom).
- In the Settings section, click **Show all** to see all available options.
- Click **List unwanted referrals**.

  - Adjust session timeout: set the session timeout in hours and minutes.
  - Adjust timer for engaged sessions: select the number of seconds it takes for a session to be considered an engaged session.
- Click **Save**.